# How to debug docker application running by gunicorn by PyCharm

Tags: python, docker, debugging, pycharm, gunicorn

I have django rest framework application with socket.io which is run in docker using gunicorn as a WSGI-server. Here's how application is run in docker-compose:

```
 web:
    build:
      context: .
    command:
      - gunicorn
      - my_app.wsgi:application
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

I want to debug it (with breakpoints, step-by-step execution and variable watch) inside docker using PyCharm Prefessional.
I already set my Python intepreter to remote one from docker-compose:

[image]

What to do next to debug the application? It's important that it is run by gunicorn as well as I use custom worker which I want to debug as well.